# Energy levels in solids and distance to something

Tags: electrons, nuclear-physics, potential-energy

I am reading Supplement #2 to Matter and Interaction book: [Link](https://matterandinteractions.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Supplement2-Semiconductordevices.pdf)

Below question is about potential energy.

In the paragraph labelled **Energy Bands in Solids** I am very clear what they mean of energy level of single atom. Energy level here is function of distance between nucleus and electron. Later they talk about energy levels in solids. Here is quotation:

> If we assemble many such atoms to form crystalline solid, the electric potential energy of the solid is periodic in x (and y and z) with period corresponding to the distance between nuclei, as shown in Figure S2.2[image: illustration]

I cannot understand what is the distance in solids that we are measuring. Is it average distance between all nuclei and electrons or distance between one fixed nucleus and all electrons. Why is it periodic along only x, y, z? Would it be periodic if we travel along vector (1,1,1)?

Comment: The energy levels in an atom are *not* a function of the distance between the nucleus and electron. Why do think that they are?

Comment: @mike this is what the very first paragraph says: `We have typically plotted U as a function of r, the separation of nucleus and electron`

Comment: Surely $U$ is the *potential energy* function,  not the energy level? The energy levels themselves come from solving the Schrodinger equation for the potential energy function $U$. They are not a function of position.

Comment: But they are a function of direction within the crystal, as shown on an $E$ vs $k$ diagram.

Comment: @mikestone, thank you, I updated the question.

Comment: @JonCuster, I cannot find `k`, did you mean `r`?

Comment: $k$ is the crystal momentum. Energy levels in a crystal are Bloch states, extending throughout the crystal. Position is irrelevant, momentum is king. See, for example, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/320941/what-information-can-we-extract-from-the-electronic-band-structure for an $E$ vs $k$ band structure. The capital Greek letters on the x-axis are various high symmetry momenta directions.